# NodeJS Await Priority - One Await runs before the other in the wrong order (Express, SQLite3 db.all and db.run)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite

Trying to run one asynchronous function in .exports, get the promise and then use the result in the next async function, but for some reason regardless of awaits, the second function goes before the first one.

sales.js =

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database/stock.db', (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err.message)
    //console.log('Connected to the "stock.db" SQlite database.')
})

module.exports = {

total: function(cartlist) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var total = 0
    for (x in cartlist){
        console.log(cartlist[x].price)
        total = total + cartlist[x].price
    }
    //console.log(total)
    resolve(total)
})},

stockloss: function(cartlist) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var barcodes = []
    const len = (cartlist).length
    for(x in cartlist){
        var inp = JSON.stringify(cartlist[x].name)
        const sql = "SELECT barcode_id FROM products WHERE name ="+inp+";"
        db.all(sql, (err, data) => {
            if (err) console.error(err.message)
            barcodes = barcodes.concat(data)
            console.log(barcodes)
        })}
    resolve(barcodes)
})},

update: function(bars) {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
    for(x in bars){
        var bar = JSON.stringify(bars[x])
        console.log(bar)
        const sql = "UPDATE levels WHERE product_id ="+bar+" SET stock_level = stock_level - 1;"
        db.run(sql, function(err) {
            if (err) console.error(err.message)
            console.log("Record updated. ")
        })}
    resolve()
})}
}
}
```

index.js (parts) =

```
'use strict'

const express = require('express')

const handlebars = require('express-handlebars').create({defaultLayout: 'main'})
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine)
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')

const port = 8080

const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose()

const db = new sqlite3.Database('./database/stock.db', (err) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err.message)
    console.log('Connected to the "stock.db" SQlite database.')
})

const sales = require('./sale.js')
```

.
.
.

```
app.get('/checkout', async(req, res) => {
    total = await sales.total(cartlist)
    var bars = await sales.stockloss(cartlist)
    var prom = await sales.update(bars)
    cartlist = []
    res.render('checkout', {total})
    total = 0
})
```

.
.
.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong with the promises, or I don't understand the async functions enough. Potentially there are problems with the db.run as well, as I keep seeing different sources on how to update data.

Comment: how do you know that prom isn't running after bars? you confirmed this with console logs?

Comment: Yes, I had console.log tests and when I put one before the for.loop in the prom function it ran before the bars array was returned.

Comment: and you're not getting any unhandled promise rejections ? (you should try/catch your awaits btw)

Comment: Haven't had any appear in the console, nope. Still new to this language so slowly learning but thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: I think your code is working in the correct order but maybe you should put a log between the two awaits for the results of `stockloss` instead of putting a log inside the funtions.

Comment: Ok, doing that does show that they run in the correct order, but then I'm confused as to why the bars array doesn't properly get passed into the prom async function

Comment: It seems to skip over the for loops and head straight to the resolve, thus providing an empty array. I don't know why it skips the for loop and db connections though.

Comment: thats because `db.all` is asynchronous

Comment: put your for loop in another function that returns a promise and await the complete result of `db.all` or put the await keyword before `db.all` and make the function async (assuming the library supports it)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i would do it:

```
async function fetchFromDb(sql) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
            db.all(sql, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
            console.error(err.message)
            reject(err)
            }
            resolve(data)
        })}
    }

async function updateRecord(sql) {
    return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
        db.run(sql, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err.message)
                reject(err)
            }
            console.log("Record updated. ")
        resolve()
        }
    }
}


module.exports = {

    total: function(cartlist) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            var total = 0
            for (x in cartlist) {
                console.log(cartlist[x].price)
                total = total + cartlist[x].price
            }
            //console.log(total)
            resolve(total)
        })
    },

    stockloss: async function(cartlist) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            var barcodes = []
            const len = (cartlist).length
            for (x in cartlist) {
                var inp = JSON.stringify(cartlist[x].name)
                const sql = "SELECT barcode_id FROM products WHERE name =" + inp + ";"
                barcodes = barcodes.concat(await fetchFromDb(sql))
                resolve(barcodes)
            }
        })
    },

    update: async function(bars) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            for (x in bars) {
                var bar = JSON.stringify(bars[x])
                console.log(bar)
                const sql = "UPDATE levels WHERE product_id =" + bar + " SET stock_level = stock_level - 1;"
                try {
                    await updateRecord(sql)
                } catch (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }
                resolve('successfully updated record')
            }
        })
    }
}
```

this is untested btw but it should work or at least help you get the right idea. `fetchFromDb` exists somewhere in your file or in your object. The main issue is to turn the callback into a promise so that you can await the result and concat the result before your resolve runs... which was the problem. Callbacks do not return results outside the function synchronously. Which is the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's giving me some errors regarding syntax but I'll work with it and see how it goes.

Comment: there was an extra brace after `fetchFromDb` function.. Ive edited it out

Comment: It keeps telling me there's a 'missing ) after argument list' at the 'barcodes = barcodes.concat(await fetchFromDb(sql))' line. If you have any idea what's causing that?

Comment: there was another missing brace. edited it to fix that

Comment: This error still errors sadly. No idea what it's asking for.

Comment: try it now..ive also edited your update function to use async await

Comment: It's still yelling about the await sadly. Thanks for your help though. Might need to entirely rethink how I'm going to do this.

Comment: Completely redid the method and managed to merge the two which fixed the await problems. Thanks for you help, all solved now!